# I want to output the python input as it is

Tags: python

i want this result.

```
---input---
"""
* name
 - jon
* age
 - 20
* hobby
 - walk
"""

--- output ---
* name
 - jon
* age
 - 20
* hobby
 - walk
----------------
```

I want to print as it is entered

Here is the code I wrote.

```
val = ""
vals = []
while True:
    val = input()
    if val == 'q':
        break
    else:
        vals.append(val)

print(vals)
```

result

```
['* name', ' - jon', '* age', ' - 20', '* hobby', ' - walk']
```

help me!!!!

Comment: `print('\n'.join(vals))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of ways to do this.

1. Print each item in a `for` loop.

```
    for val in vals:
        print(val)
```

2. Join the list items into a string, each item separated by newlines, then print that.

```
     print("\n".join(vals))
```

3. Treat the items of the list as separate arguments to `print()` and use a newline as a separator.

```
    print(*vals, sep="\n")
```

I like #3 because it`s short and it doesn't create a temporary string containing all the items like #2.